# Fresh Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Installation will only boot into grub mode

Tags: ubuntu, partition, system-installation, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (minimal setup with default partitioning and security encryption) on a laptop with a 120 GB SSD drive.

When I try to boot, it will only load into command line grub mode (GNU GRUB version 2.02). `ls` output gives me the following:

```
(hd0) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)

ls (hd0,gpt3)/
error: unkown filesytem

ls (hd0,gpt2)/
./ ../ lost+found/ efi/ grub/ ... and then seems to list the kernels e.g. vmlinuz-4.15.0-23-generic

ls (hd0,gpt1)/
efi/
```

Boot mode in my BIOS is set to UEFI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what worked for me.  (Needs internet connection):

1. Workaround to boot into Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

   ([@jas-](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454378/299011) is right.  Tab key autocomplete helps!)

   From the `grub>` prompt:

   ```
   configfile /efi/grub/grub.cfg
   ```

   alternatively

   ```
   configfile (hd0,gpt1)/efi/grub/grub.cfg
   ```
2. Once logged into the running system, from a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), reinstall Grub for UEFI boot:

   ```
   sudo su -
   apt install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64 linux-generic linux-headers-generic
   ```

   At the prompt for which configuration file to use, I selected the first option, use the package maintainer's files.

   Then

   ```
   update-initramfs -c -k all
   ```
3. Done!

#### Command Sources

- Workaround for Grub booting found in **Ubuntu Documentation** > **Grub2/Troubleshooting** > **Specific Troubleshooting** > **grub>** > **Quick Fix**
  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting#grub.3E-1
- Reinstall steps modified from System76 support article.  Did not need to `chroot` to fix, since I could boot into the actual system. **GRUB - Repair GRUB Bootloader**
  https://support.system76.com/articles/grub/#for-sata-drives
- May be related to:

  > - Doing an "Entire disk" installation over an existing LVM installation will fail because the installer selects the wrong boot device ([1724417](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1724417)) Use custom partitioning instead and manually select the right boot device in the combo box.
  >     https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Desktop

Comment: The most likely cause of this is that you chose a filesystem that grub doesn't understand, like JFS. In that case, no amount of configfile <somecrap>grub.cfg will help you...

Answer (score 3):

Grub understands most Linux filesystems; you will want to use commands like the following to identify the filename for your kernel and your initrd and your root device:

- ls (hd0,gpt3)/
- ls (hd0,gpt2)/
- ls (hd0,gpt1)/

Use that approach to find your kernel, and you should be able to boot with a set of commands like this, I believe:

- set root=(hd0,gpt3)
- linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.888.35-14-generic root=/dev/sda1
- initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.888.35-14-generic
- boot

Comment: The kernel seems to sit on (hd0,gpt2). Following your guide, I was able to identify and load the latest kernel that I could find. This would then take me into a new terminal (BusyBox v1.27.2 built-in shell) with a (initramfs) prompt. Any idea how to proceed from here?

Comment: That's a good step forward; I'd look very carefully over that output to see why it did not boot further. It may be that the root= line was incorrect for your install. Look in /dev in the initramfs for likely values.

Comment: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory  ----- run-init: opening console: No such file or directory ----- Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init. --------- ..... No init found....

Comment: Use grub or the busybox shell to examine the other volumes, I'm guessing they're /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sda3 and figure out which one should be used for the root= flag.

Comment: I have tried to set root for the kernel to /dev/sda, /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3 with the same mounting error and init not found. Any idea?

Comment: Oh, this may have to do with the encryption setup you mentioned above, if you've encrypted your drive. I have not done this personally, but from GRUB you may be able to issue a command like "cryptomount (hd0,gpt3)" which should prompt you for your encryption password (or maybe it was gpt1 that you encrypted - find out). Give this a go and see if it works.

Comment: Yep, the drive is encrypted and the command line prompts you to provide your password, which works fine. The mentioned init and mounting errors happen after that step when the drive has already been unlocked.

Comment: I regret that I don't know enough about crypto in grub to take you the rest of the way to a solution, but I hope that getting this far has been useful to you. Hopefully someone else will show up here to take you the rest of the way.

Answer (score 0):

Grub has some autocomplete functionality available to determine which of the aforementioned drives contains your kernel and initramfs. That will at the very least tell you where your boot files reside. Use of the tab key can be used for autocomplete.

You can also issue the `help` command to navigate grub2's functionality.

Since you installed as and EFI kernel you will use `linux` and the `initrd` commands to load the kernel and initramfs from the vfat EFI partiton.